# Django. Некоректно работает связь ManyToMany в тестах

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты, many-to-many

В своем Django-проекте создал собственную модель User. Для нее создал несколько методов, которые проверяют наличие определенных разрешений у пользователя (использую эти методы в шаблонах, для отображения пользователям ссылок на контент, к которому они имеют доступ). Сейчас пишу тесты к проекту и дошел до тестирования данных функций. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу добавить юзеру разрешение через user.user_permissions.add(perm). Оно не сохраняется в соответствующую таблицу. На stackoverflow обнаружил несколько вопросов, в которых также обсуждается проблема, что add() и другие методы RelatedManager некорректно работают в тестах. Но нигде не смог найти ответа, почему так происходит и как это обойти. Прошу развернутого комментария. Заранее большое спасибо.

Вот так выглядит моя модель:

```
class ShelterUser(AbstractUser):
shelter = models.ForeignKey(
    Shelters,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    verbose_name="Привязан к приюту",
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "пользователя приютов"
    verbose_name_plural = "Пользователи приютов"

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.username

def has_add_pets_perm(self) -> bool:
    return self.has_perm("shelter_app.add_pets")

def has_change_pets_perm(self) -> bool:
    return self.has_perm("shelter_app.change_pets")

def has_delete_pets_perm(self) -> bool:
    return self.has_perm("shelter_app.delete_pets")
```

Вот так выглядят тесты:

```
def test_has_add_pets_perm(self):
    shelter_user = ShelterUser.objects.get(username='тестовый юзер')
    self.assertFalse(shelter_user.has_add_pets_perm())

    perm = Permission.objects.get(name='Can add Животное')
    shelter_user.user_permissions.add(perm)
    self.assertTrue(shelter_user.has_add_pets_perm())

def test_has_change_pets_perm(self):
    shelter_user = ShelterUser.objects.get(username='тестовый юзер')
    self.assertFalse(shelter_user.has_add_pets_perm())

    perm = Permission.objects.get(name='Can change Животное')
    shelter_user.user_permissions.add(perm)
    self.assertTrue(shelter_user.has_perm("shelter_app.change_pets"))
```

Результат после запуска тестов:

FAIL: test_has_add_pets_perm (shelter_app.tests.test_models.ShelterUserModelTest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gfhfa\PycharmProjects\shelter\shelter\shelter_app\tests\test_models.py", line 232, in test_has_add_pets_perm
self.assertTrue(shelter_user.has_add_pets_perm())
AssertionError: False is not true

FAIL: test_has_change_pets_perm (shelter_app.tests.test_models.ShelterUserModelTest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gfhfa\PycharmProjects\shelter\shelter\shelter_app\tests\test_models.py", line 240, in test_has_change_pets_perm
self.assertTrue(shelter_user.has_perm("shelter_app.change_pets"))
AssertionError: False is not true
FAILED (failures=2)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался самостоятельно. Проблема заключалась не в `RelatedManager`. Оказалось, что данные сохраняются в БД корректно, и я копал не в ту сторону.

Дело было в том, что при выполнении `has_perm()` у объекта юзера создается неявный аргумент `_perm_cache`, куда заносятся все разрешения. При повторном выполнении `has_perm()` бекенд проверяет, есть ли `_perm_cache` и если есть, не делает запрос к БД, а тупо соотносит искомое разрешение c содержимым `_perm_cache`.

При этом в моих тестах выполнялся сначала один `has_perm(),` затем в БД заносились данные о новом разрешении, после чего повторно выполнялся `has_perm()`. Но из-за `_perm_cache` запрос к БД не выполнялся и получалось, будто у юзера нет только что данного ему разрешения.